# download start request not working in flutter inappwebview

Tags: flutter, webview, flutter-dependencies

I have converted a website to an application using the flutter inappwebview.the urls which directly pointing to a file for eg: https://**************/abc.docx.These kind of files,I am able to download.but the files like paymentbills,profileinfo which involves several ajax requests,I am not able to download.If anyone knows the problem,please tell.I am using the ondownloadstartrequest event for downloading the file.

I tried downloading the file using the Dio.download() when i use this if the file is static ie already the url pointing to that file, it will download but links like http:/**/download(this is an ajax request link),I am not able to do the download.Why?
Another method I tried is using ajaxintercepting.I switched it to on mode in the inappwebviewsettings().
then I start calling the function of onajaxintercept when i use this some process inside the application not taking  place